# ltrace for Android build

Tags: android, android-ndk, ltrace

guys. I'm trying to buidl ltrace for Android from this repo https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/ltrace/ .
So i've installed android-ndk, then i've done everything like in android manual for using standalone toolchain for arm and android-16 (https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html Advanced method from here).
Then i've cloned the repo and in root directory run ./autogen.sh . 
After that ./configure -host=arm-linux .
And i've received an error:
"configure: error: *** libelf.h or gelf.h not found on your system"

So it's look like i need include libelf from /platform/external/elfutils(also android source code) .
But i haven't got any idea how to do that, this repo contains only Android.mk, and i don't know how to build it with ndk-build. 
It gives me an error, that i haven't var NDK_PROJECT_PATH, but after i have set it, project haven't build too.

Can anybody help ?