# Build ltrace for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, cross-compiling, ltrace

I'm trying to build ltrace for Android.
I've followed these commands:

```
    export SYS_ROOT="/home/pedro/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-19/arch-x86"
    export CC="/home/pedro/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/i686-linux-android-gcc --sysroot=$SYS_ROOT"
    export PATH="/home/pedro/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/:$PATH"
```

and then:

```
    ./configure --host=i686-linux
```

But I've received this error:

```
    checking gelf.h usability... no
    checking gelf.h presence... no
    checking for gelf.h... no
    configure: error: *** libelf.h or gelf.h not found on your system
```

I've also tried:

```
    ./configure --host=i686-linux --with-libelf=/usr/local
```

And received:

```
    checking gelf.h usability... no
    checking gelf.h presence... yes
    checking for gelf.h... no
    configure: error: *** libelf.h or gelf.h not found on your system
```

I've found a similar/same problem here
[ltrace for Android build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33107795/ltrace-for-android-build)
but since nobody has replied and it was months ago I made the question again. I hope there is no problem.
Can anybody help me with this problem or with another way so I could build ltrace for Android?
Thank you.

Comment: Hi Pedro.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You should not have created a new question but rather up-voted the question / favorited it and left a comment to generate activity on it.

Comment: Oh... sorry. I tried to comment but I couldn't because I don't have 50 reputation, so I thought this was the only way. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

ltrace has a dependency on libelf. This means you need to also cross-compile libelf for Android, and point the ltrace build to the cross-compiled libelf with `--with-libelf`. When you specify `--with-libelf=/usr/local`, you're pointing the ltrace build to the version of libelf built for your host machine.

Comment: I've tried that but it didn't work for me. It gave me the same error as before. Any idea?

Comment: You absolutely need the cross-compiled libelf for this to work, so my guess would be that you're either passing the path incorrectly or there's an underlying issue in the configure script. You can figure out what went wrong by looking at the configure code, and adding a couple of print statements if necessary. Unfortunately I don't know any better ways to debug configure issues.